# How to set content-length-range in FineUploader S3?

Tags: fine-uploader

When `content-length-range` is set by validation, it results in files greater than that size not being able to be added to the uploader at all:

```
    validation: {
      sizeLimit: 1048576
    },
```

How can I just set `content-length-range` without any other bells/whistles?

Comment: Why would you want to allow a user to submit a file that will ultimately be rejected by S3?

Comment: @RayNicholus Fineuploader will take the image and scale it down until it's within the size limit, then upload it.

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't thought of this. I assume you also set `scaling.sendOriginal` to `false`?

Comment: Effectively yes, the original images is cancelled. It loops `scaleImage`, and when the size is small enough (usually on the first iteration), it `cancel(idOriginal)` and `addFiles(scaledBlob)`.

Comment: Oh, I see, you are calling the `scaleImage` method yourself after the file has been submitted. I think there are a couple options here. I'll explain both in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to leave the [`validation.sizeLimit` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#validation.sizeLimit) alone in this case and set a [properly formatted `content-length-range` parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html#sigv4-ConditionMatching) via the [`request.params` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-s3.html#request.params). Fine Uploader S3 will include these params in the policy document (if a policy document is used). Another option would be to maintain two separate Fine Uploader instances. One instance accepts files from the user w/out `validation`. That instance is also used to scale images, which are then passed into the "main" Fine Uploader S3 instance via the [`addFiles` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addFiles). This "main" instance has `validation` set.

Comment: I tried `params: {conditions: ["content-length-range", 1024, 1048576]}` and it adds this to the policy document: `{'x-amz-meta-conditions': 'content-length-range%2C1024%2C1048576'},`. Would it be possible to have Fineuploader use a policy document generated entirely server-side?

Comment: Ah yes, unless it is mentioned in the `UNPREFIXED_PARAM_NAMES` array in s3/util.js, it will add the x-amz-meta prefix. So that will probably need to be added to the library. A pull request can solve that. Other choice is to go with the 2nd option in my answer above.

Comment: Sorry to keep bringing this up, I'd really like a definitive answer: Is it possible to manually set the policy document with Fineuploader (as opposed to filling in all the options and having the library generate the policy document)? Being able to do that would solve a bunch of problems for me, and likely improve performance.

Comment: No, that isn't possible. There really shouldn't be any performance concerns associated w/ generating a policy document.

Comment: Also note that policy documents are not used for chunked requests.

Comment: If you will excuse me for straying slightly off-topic for a moment: By improving performance, what I had in mind was the front-end POSTing an integer that is the number of images to upload. The backend will generate that number of policy documents for the full-size images and another set for each thumbnail size, then return all the policy documents in that single response. Since it's not possible to set the policy document for each item manually in FineUploader, perhaps it's better to try and do it from scratch, I just don't yet know how to make a javascript uploader this complicated.

Comment: Unless you can demonstrate a significant performance improvement by going that route, I wouldn't suggest spending time on that. And I would be a bit surprised to see anything notable. Duplicating much of the logic in Fine Uploader S3 will be quite a bit of work. Instead, you will want to follow one of the suggestions in my answer or follow-up comments.

Comment: It's done: https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/pull/1625 In the meantime (if/when the changes appear on cdnjs), is it possible to do some overriding or inheriting on `qq.s3.util` so I can work with it for now?

Comment: you can certainly modify your local copy. We'll talk more in the PR. May need adjustments + tests to be sure this works.